# How to remove textfield border

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I want to remove the borders of a UITextField, but keeping the rounded shape to have this kind of result :

[image]

I already changed the textfield background color in the interface builder.

If I choose the "no border" option, the text field is no longer rounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From interface builder change it to no border.
Then in viewcontroller write:

```
textfield.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrey
textfield.layer.cornerRadius = 5
```

Comment: Ok nice then I have another problem, the text is too near to the left border of the textField, how to indent it ?

Comment: @Placard That's a new question. Please do some research then post a new question with all relevant details if needed.

Comment: Okay i'll do, sorry !